# Toggle state where user can delete text in textbox vs not delete text

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I have a checkbox in my app. When the user checks the checkbox I need my textarea to populate with text that cannot be removed. They can add to the text, but they can't remove it.

So if the string is `Hello my name is`, I want to add that to the textarea and they can't delete but they can only add their name.

However, if they uncheck the checkbox, I need to remove the text `Hello my name is` and the user is simply allowed to type whatever they want. I'm struggling with the part where if they check the checkbox and uncheck it again that they are able to type...

Here is what I have:

```
addHelloMyNameIs(val) {
let message = "Hello my name is";
let isChat = val; // val is true or false
var readOnlyLength = message.length;
console.log(isChat)
  this.postTextarea = message + this.postTextarea;
  $('#newPostTextarea .text-input').on('keypress, keydown', function(event) {
    if(isChat) {
      if ((event.which != 37 && (event.which != 39)) &&
        ((this.selectionStart < readOnlyLength) ||
          ((this.selectionStart == readOnlyLength) && (event.which == 8)))) {
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    }
  });
 }


cancelHelloMyNameIs() {
    this.addHelloMyNameIs(false)
    this.postTextarea = this.postTextarea.replace("Hello my name is ", "")
    this.postTextarea = this.postTextarea.replace("Hello my name is", "")
  }
```

But this doesn't work, as when the user checks and then unchecks, they are unable to type again.

How can I fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working stackblitz for you https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nd7srq

This is a minimalist example so you can clearly see what is going on and can copy any relevant bits.

Code as follows:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

const START = 'Hello my name is '

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  checked = false;
  taContent = '';

  checkChanged() {
    if (this.checked) {
      this.taContent = START + this.taContent;
    } else {
      this.taContent = this.taContent.split(START)[1];
    }
  }

  taChanged(txt) {
    if (this.checked) {
      if (txt.startsWith(START)) this.taContent = txt;
      else {
        const tmp = this.taContent;
        this.taContent = '';
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.taContent = tmp;
        })
      }
    } else {
      this.taContent = txt;
    }
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<br>
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="checked" (change)="checkChanged()">
<br>
<br>
<textarea [ngModel]="taContent" (ngModelChange)="taChanged($event)">
</textarea>
```